# How to program stm8s003f3p6 using UART?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, uart, bootloader, stm8

I am new to stm8s series of microcontroller. I want to program stm8s003f3p6 via UART but there is no inbuilt bootloader in it. So is it possible to burn custom bootloader? How should I start? Is there any reference?

Comment: "easy" depends on what you find easy, we won't be able to answer that for you. If you've written bootloaders before, probably easy.

Comment: "Is there any reference?" I trust you can go onto the product page, click on "Documentation" and then click on "bootloader FAQ".

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to my question . It may help others. Please see [this post](https://lujji.github.io/blog/serial-bootloader-for-stm8/) for answer.

Post in above link explains, how to write bootloader for stm8s003f3p6. Also there is Python program of uploader. Github Link for the code is given at the last of the post

Comment: (-1): [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - Provide context for links
"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: Sorry .Now I added some context of post. Is it ok now?

Comment: Don't worry. You've added context, but ideally you should still "always quote the most relevant part in case the external resource is unreachable" - i.e. the most relevant instruction or code snippet. It's understandable if you're not sure what such quote should be, since the linked reference is new info for you. You can always complement your answer later.